# how to create list each item as another list?

Tags: c#, list, listitem

i am trying create one list item as another list.i need that list every item has one another list.i created string as list for one loop. and next loop i needs each item as one list to insert data based on range.
how to do this..??

my code:

```
List<string> l = new List<string>(s.Split(';'));
foreach (string item in l) 
{
    if (item.Contains("-"))
    {    
        List<string> parts = new List<string>();
        int min = Int32.Parse(parts[0]);
        int max = Int32.Parse(parts[1]);
        for (int m = min; m <= max; m++)
        {
            // add the value in i to the data
            cmd = "insert into quickcom values('" + destination + "','" + codes + "','" + prefix + "','" + rate + "','" + level + "','" + m + "','" + effective_date + "','" + company_id + "')";

            cmd = ReplaceSpecialCharacters(cmd);

            MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(cmd, sqlCon);
            var i = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd = "";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (item.Contains(";"))
        {
            List<string> parts = new List<string>(s.Split(';'));

            cmd = "insert into quickcom values('" + destination + "','" + codes + "','" + prefix + "','" + rate + "','" + level + "','" + s + "','" + effective_date + "','" + company_id + "')";

            cmd = ReplaceSpecialCharacters(cmd);

            MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(cmd, sqlCon);
            var i = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd = "";
        }
    }
}
```

help me...
thnx

Comment: can you show sample input data?

Comment: if (item.Contains(";")) is always false.

Answer (score 1):

if you have two delimiters to break each record and each item of the record, then you can directly get list of string list as below

```
string s = "a2-b2-c2-d2-e2;a3-b4-c2-d2-e2";
var list  = s.Split(';').Select(s1 => s1.Split('-').ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need, but you can create a list whose items are in turns lists of strings by using the following type: `List<List<string>>`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a List, containing other Lists:

```
List<List<string>> g = new List<List<string>>();
```

And then just add your "parts" to this list:

```
g.Add(parts);
```

Hope I understood you correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Your code above is only part, and doesn't work in my computer.
So I just write some comment:
 1. List parts = new List(); **parts** is a varialble never used here.
 2. I want to see the details of **ReplaceSpecialCharacters**.
 3. cmd = "insert into ... you'd better replace it with **string.Format**("insert into ..{0}..{1}",para0,para1...)
 4. List l = new List(**s**.Split(';')); it helps a lot if you list some examples of string **s** here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want is `List<List<string>>` but that's what I'm assuming:

```
var l = new List<string>(s.Split(';'));
var aggregatedList = new List<List<string>>();

foreach (var item in l)
{
    if (item.IndexOf("-") > -1)
    {
        var a = item.Split('-').Select(n => int.Parse(n)).ToArray();
        var parts = Enumerable.Range(a[0], a[1]-a[0]+1).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();
        aggregatedList.Add(parts);
    }
}
```